# Iterate only unseen messages in IMAP with Laminas Mail

Tags: php, laminas

We can count unseen messages with:

```
$unreadMessages = $mail->countMessages([Storage::FLAG_UNSEEN]);
```

How to iterate only those unseen messages?
When I iterate all messages (as shown in [documentation](https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-mail/read/)), it's painfully slow.

```
foreach ($mail as $messageNum => $message) {
        if ($message->hasFlag(Storage::FLAG_SEEN) && !$message->hasFlag(Storage::FLAG_UNSEEN) && !$message->hasFlag(Storage::FLAG_RECENT)) {
            // echo PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL . "Skipping seen/not-recent e-mail from " . $message->from . PHP_EOL;
            continue;
        }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When you look into how countMessages() function is done, you find out that protocol search function can be used. But protocol is private. So you have to extend the class:

```
class MyImap extends Laminas\Mail\Storage\Imap
{
    public function getProtocol()
    {
        return $this->protocol;
    }
}

$mail = new MyImap(...);
```

Then you can use this for fast iterating only unseen messages:

```
$message_nums = $mail->getProtocol()->search(['UNSEEN']);
foreach ($message_nums as $messageNum) {
        $message = $mail->getMessage($messageNum);
}
```